# Chip inductors without voltage rating - how to interpret?

Tags: voltage, inductor, maximum-ratings

During the search for a suitable chip inductor I noticed, that many producers don't mention a voltage rating in the datasheet.

How to understand that? Does it mean, as long as I don't exceed the rated current, the voltage doesn't matter?
Or is there some underlying general definition of voltage rating?

Some examples:

https://product.tdk.com/info/en/documents/catalog/inductor_commercial_decoupling_nlcv32-pf_en.pdf
https://www.digikey.com/en/datasheets/taiyo-yuden/taiyo-yuden-wound01_e
[image]

Comment: `as long as I don't exceed the rated current, the voltage doesn't matter?` Not exactly. There should be some limitations due to the package dimensions. For example, the max applicable voltage to a 0805-case chip **resistor** is around 200V. So I think that there's a similar limitation for chip inductors as well.

Comment: ... however achieving 200V across the inductor within the rated current may not be easily achievable...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you send a DC current of 40 mA through a 4.5 Ω inductor, the voltage drop is 0.18 V.

You cannot apply a higher DC voltage without exceeding the current.

For AC voltages, the inductor's impedance is higher, but the voltage drop apparently does not become dangerous.